cyclic and/or multiple xsl:include in xslt 3 code
I have a non trivial set of XSLT code in a library where I have ended up (quite understandly) with some cyclic and/or multiple includes of the same file.
So...
`Warning at xsl:stylesheet on line 10 column 63 of value.xslt:
SXWN9019  Stylesheet module
file:.....value.xslt
is included or imported more than once. This is permitted, but may lead to errors or
unexpected behavior
Error at xsl:function on line 59 column 54 of value.xslt:
XTSE0770  Function value:getValue#1 is declared twice - see .../value.xslt#59
....
`
I've only recently done this (to simplify the structure of the code) and, it breaks.
Having investigated this my understand that this is valid in some contexts (as the error message indicates), but doesn't really work, (as the error message indicates)...which is a tad confusing, I assume there is some scenario where this does work, but I'm breaking the rules.
How do I do this? (this is common issue in other languages, I remember using #defines in .h files in C, and F#, for example, doesn't allow cycles, but has quite sophisticated ways to wriggle around the issue).
(SaxonHE12-4J\saxon-he-12.4.jar)

due to feedback from Martin Honnen, I've changed all includes for import.
This works, but I still get the warning, which is worrying, what can go wrong?

It says "Warning" so it is not clear what breaks.

its not formatted very well, it does say ‘error’ though the newline has been aborbed

ie it doesnt like seeing a function twice

Yes, I see it now, the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#err-XTSE0770 indeed says "It is a static error for a package to contain two or more xsl:function declarations with the same expanded QName, the same arity, and the same import precedence, unless there is another xsl:function declaration with the same expanded QName and arity, and a higher import precedence.". So unless you manage to create a different import precedence it is not supposed to work.

https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dt-import-precedence explains import precedence.

im slightly surprised the 2nd include isnt simply ignored, it seems unnecesarily strict

i could try import, but tbh, ive always felt it is doing something i explicitly dont really want to do, but these are just functions so it probably doesnt matter

Basically, including a module twice isn't in itself an error, but if the module contains any named components such as functions, variables, or named templates, then it's likely to lead to an error because you can't have two named components with the same name.
The answer to the question "how do I do this" is that you don't need to, because everything you include is available globally throughout the stylesheet.
It can be a problem if you're trying to include code that you don't want to change, but if that's not a constraint, the simplest solution is to move all includes to the top level. Alternatively, learn about xsl:import -- but that can bring its own set of problems.

ah ok, I've avoided import because it seems to be more complex. I can refactor the code, but the intention is to have modules that include modules they are dependent on, but modules can be independently included in some parent client code, so the cycles and repeats are a bit inherent. It works with import, I still get the warning but the warning worries me. FYI these are really just functions.

ah interestingly now I get an intermittent issue with a tail recursive function...sometimes it works, sometimes i get a stack overflow....so maybe I've answered my own question

I suspect it may 'see' the recursive function more than once, and maybe it decides if its the same function, it correctly wires it up, and if it doesnt it doesnt, I'll look up import

hmmmm...maybe I should be using packages?

for the moment I've created a file that is effectively the closure of all the included files (i.e. a file that just lists the includes), and then included that, not ideal though.
